# How to print -0x4(%rbp) in gdb?

Tags: gdb, cpu-registers

In the disassembly there's such code:

```
movl   $0x6,-0x4(%rbp)
```

I try to print the value this way but fails:

```
(gdb) p  0x4(%esp)
A syntax error in expression, near `%esp)'.
(gdb) p 0x4+$esp
Argument to arithmetic operation not a number or boolean.
```

How to print it correctly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks like you're working with 64 bit code, in which case you just need, e.g.:

```
(gdb) p $rbp-0x4
$1 = (void *) 0x7fff5fbff71c
```

If you want to see what's actually *at* this address, then you need to cast the `void *` address, e.g.

```
(gdb) p /x *(int *)($rbp-0x4)
$2 = 0x7fff
```

or, more succinctly, use `x` instead of `p`, e.g.

```
(gdb) x /w $rbp-0x4
0x7fff5fbff71c: 0x00007fff
```

Comment: You could also use: `(gdb) x/w $rbp-0x4`

Comment: @Karmastan: cool - thanks - I'll add that as an alternative in the answer

Comment: x /w * $rbp-0x4, should be x /w $rbp-0x4

Comment: To see what's there as a 64-bit quantity in hex:
x/xg $rbp-0x4