# In GDB how do I print 0xc(%rsp)?

Tags: gdb, x86-64

I'm trying to debug some code for a project and I've come up against this line `cmpl $0x7,0xc(%rsp)`. What is 0xc(%rsp), and how do I print it?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5455832/1758762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is 0xc(%rsp)

The memory location 12 bytes above current stack pointer. The value at that location is being compared with `7`.

> and how do I print it?

```
(gdb) print $rsp+0xc
```