# Print (%r12,%rbx,1) in GDB

Tags: x86, gdb, memory-address, att, addressing-mode

[In GDB how do I print 0xc(%rsp)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212339/in-gdb-how-do-i-print-0xcrsp)

I saw the above link to print the value when there's two arguments there, but what do I do when there's three? What to do with the offset 1?

How to find the address of (%r12,%rbx,1) and print its content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In x86/x86-64 AT&T syntax the addresses are of the form `displacement(basereg, indexreg, scale)`. That is computed to an address as *displacement+basereg+indexreg*scale* where *scale* is 1, 2, 4, or 8. You can leave any part of the equation off. In GDB you can [`print`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html#Data) the address from such an expression using the `print` command. For example address 0x28(%rdx, %rsi, 4) could be printed with GDB with:

```
print 0x28+$rdx+$rsi*4
```

If you want to print out what is at such an address you can use GDB's [`x` (examine) command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html). To print the string at that address out you can use:

```
x/s 0x28+$rdx+$rsi*4
```

To display a byte at that address in hexadecimal:

```
x/bx 0x28+$rdx+$rsi*4
```

To display the 12 16-bit signed values starting at that address in decimal:

```
x/12hd 0x28+$rdx+$rsi*4
```

To display the 6 32-bit unsigned values starting at that address in decimal:

```
x/6wu 0x28+$rdx+$rsi*4
```

To display the 3 64-bit values starting at that address in hexadecimal:

```
x/3gx 0x28+$rdx+$rsi*4
```

Review the complete documentation for the eXamine command at the link provided earlier for a complete description of the command and its parameters.

---

In your example you don't have a displacement so it is assumed to be 0. The GDB expression for `(%r12,%rbx,1)` is `0+$r12+$rbx*1` which can be simplified to `$r12+$rbx`

Comment: I tried something like that before, but I got a bunch of weird numbers. Maybe I mistyped something somewhere. I just tried your way and it works now. Thank you so much.