# Meaning of 0x8($rsp)

Tags: assembly, gdb, x86-64, disassembly

My first time learning Assembly Lang. Here is a part of (gdb) disassembly:

```
mov    $0x131,%eax
cmp    0x8(%rsp),%eax  //Question here, what is the value of 0x8(%rsp)?




(gdb)i r
rax            0x131    305
rbx            0x7fffffffe578   140737488348536
rcx            0x20     32
rdx            0x7fffffffe478   140737488348280
rsi            0x0      0
rdi            0x1999999999999999       1844674407370955161
rbp            0x0      0x0
rsp            0x7fffffffe470   0x7fffffffe470
r8             0x37ed3bb080     240203313280
r9             0x0      0
r10            0x1e     30
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x400cb0 4197552
r13            0x7fffffffe570   140737488348528
r14            0x0      0
r15            0x0      0
rip            0x400fd9 0x400fd9 <phase_3+129>
eflags         0x212    [ AF IF ]
cs             0x33     51
ss             0x2b     43
ds             0x0      0
es             0x0      0
fs             0x0      0
```

I have trouble figuring out what does it compare. and what is the value of `0x8(%rsp)`.

(I know this question sounds like stupid)

Thanks in advance

=-==========

Finally I solved by

```
(gdb) p /x *(int *)($rsp+0x8)
```

with the help of this post [How to print -0x4(%rbp) in gdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455832/how-to-print-0x4rbp-in-gdb)

Zack's answer should be right, but it is not working since I'm using a 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parentheses generally mean to dereference. `0x8(%rsp)` means "get the location on the stack that is 8 bytes away from the stack pointer `%rsp`, and then take the value at that address."

It moves `0x131` into `%eax`, and then compares it to the data at that location. cmp sets the `eflags` register depending on that comparison (like the Zero Flag if the operands were equal, etc.)

To see what is at the address using GDB, type

```
(gdb) x/1dw 0x8($esp)
```

This command `x` examines memory.

- 1 means examine 1 of whatever unit is specified.
- `d` means output in decimal notation (as opposed to hex). I don't know what type of data you are making a comparison to, so you might use `c` to get a char, or `x` to get a hex, or `s` for a string, or whatever.
- `w` provides the unit, in this case a word, which is 4 bytes.

So this command looks at 4 bytes at the given address, `0x8(%rsp)`, and prints whatever is there in decimal format.

Note that [accessing register contents includes using `$` in place of `%`.](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Registers.html#Registers)

To learn more about using GDB to see how your memory is changing, reference [§10.6 in the user documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html).

Comment: For my 64bit OS, (gdb) p /x *(int *)($rsp+0x8) works for me. x/1dw 0x8(%esp) will cause a syntax error in 64bit OS. Anyway, your answer is really helpful, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Because the program allocated some stack memory by subtracting the stack pointer. Now when it want to use the allocated stack memory, they need to use a offset to dereference.